# bash - parameter substitution until line break

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

I have a .txt file that contains a text like this :

```
{remove}Some text in line 1
Some text in line 2
Some text in line 3
{remove} Some text in line 4
```

With Parameter expansion how can I delete all lines that contain the special tag {remove} ??

I tried this but it doesn't work !

```
text="$(cat "template.txt")"
echo "${text##\{remove\}*'\n'}"
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have extglobs enabled? Do you mind enabling them?

Comment: To remove lines, use `grep`:  `text=$(grep -v '^{remove}' template.txt)`.

Comment: @Alfe, obviously that's possible. The question, as I read it, is whether this can be done with parameter expansions. That's what makes it an interesting question. :)

Comment: (By the way -- I'd tend to suggest restricting this technique to smaller files; parameter expansions aren't always as efficient as they could/should be with large buffers, overwhelming even the fork/exec overhead of launching a tool like grep or sed with large enough content).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, well, considering that OP didn't explicitly state that this question is of academical interest and about solving an issue using a very special (and obviously unfit) approach (for an unexplained reason), I assumed that just solving the issue was the main interest ;-)

Comment: @Alfe, if all they wanted was to solve the problem the best way possible, why would anyone ask how to do something "with X" or "using X", ever? By definition, such qualifiers restrict the solution space; as such, they can never improve the quality of the best applicable answer given; they can only ever make it worse.

Comment: ...anyhow, getting exactly the answer one asked for is the appropriate reward for such a suboptimally filtered question. :)

Comment: My experience is that some asking "how do I get this screw into the wall using that hammer" maybe just isn't reconsidering their choice of tool.

Comment: I'm not sure about "obviously unfit" -- for small enough buffers, the PE approach will be significantly faster to run (via avoiding fork/exec overhead). The approach given by Tim shares this advantage, but reduces the downside (scaling with input size in a manner clearly defined as O(n) rather than implementation-dependent). Whether the OP was considering these factors in asking the question... well, we'll only know if they tell us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, because you can't stop shell-pattern `*`s from being greedy.

What you can do is use an extglob to match only characters other than the newline:

```
shopt -s extglob
text=$(<template.txt)
echo "${text//'{remove}'*([!$'\n'])/}"
```

That will leave empty lines; if you want to remove those lines entirely, then you need to be sure that the string itself contains a trailing newline (or else the last line will never match the pattern):

```
shopt -s extglob
text=$(<template.txt)$'\n'
printf %s "${text//'{remove}'*([!$'\n'])$'\n'/}"
```

...using `printf` rather than `echo` above to avoid doubling that trailing newline.

Comment: nice +1, but this will indeed remove the content but still print blank line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true, I posted that comment to soon :)

Comment: a **gross** way to chomp the trailing newlines: `echo "$(echo "${text//'{remove}'*([!$'\n'])?($'\n')/}")"` -- does not require manually tacking a newline to the end of the string first.

Comment: Thank you! It's working :-D
Ps: I like your approach

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way. Just read string line-by-line and check if it contains the substring:

```
string="{remove}Some text in line 1
Some text in line 2
Some text in line 3
{remove} Some text in line 4"

while read -r line; do
if [[ $line != *"{remove}"* ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
fi
done <<< "$string"
```

There are also other ways, as one that was commented by @Alfe .

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "$line"`, or at least `echo "$line"`, would be improvements. To show a case where `printf` works but `echo` doesn't, consider a line with only `-n`. Whereas `echo $line` with no quotes will very, very much do the wrong thing with a line of `*`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're absolutely right, I've already edited the post.